# Could not download https://geo.pkg.julialang.org/registries exception when downloading a Julia package

Tags: julia

I just downloaded a clean install of Julia 1.8 using the M1 mac binaries. When I went to download a new package (in this case Flux), I got the following warning:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> add Flux
┌ Warning: could not download https://geo.pkg.julialang.org/registries
│   exception = Could not resolve host: geo.pkg.julialang.org while requesting https://geo.pkg.julialang.org/registries
└ @ Pkg.Registry /Users/administrator/.julia/scratchspaces/a66863c6-20e8-4ff4-8a62-49f30b1f605e/agent-cache/default-macmini-aarch64-1.0/build/default-macmini-aarch64-1-0/julialang/julia-release-1-dot-8/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Registry/Registry.jl:68
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
    Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/HolyLabRegistry`
    Updating git-repo `https://github.com/HolyLab/HolyLabRegistry`
   Resolving package versions...
┌ Warning: could not download https://geo.pkg.julialang.org/registries
│   exception = Could not resolve host: geo.pkg.julialang.org while requesting https://geo.pkg.julialang.org/registries
└ @ Pkg.Registry /Users/administrator/.julia/scratchspaces/a66863c6-20e8-4ff4-8a62-49f30b1f605e/agent-cache/default-macmini-aarch64-1.0/build/default-macmini-aarch64-1-0/julialang/julia-release-1-dot-8/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.8/Pkg/src/Registry/Registry.jl:68
...
...
...
```

I looked online and saw [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/issues/2742) but it was not clear if there is still an active need to work around this issue or if the warning can be ignored.

Comment: I believe `https://geo.pkg.julialang.org/registries` does not exist and should be named `https://pkg.julialang.org/registries`.  While the problem seems to be with the instalator code, one possible hack would be to try to add  to the `/private/etc/hosts` the IP of the correct address `151.101.2.217` as `geo.pkg.julialang.org`. I do not have a Mac though to test.

Comment: Do you have the `JULIA_PKG_SERVER` environment variable set or something?

Comment: I did a fresh install of Julia 1.8, would the env vars carry over from Release candidates or the like?

Comment: Environment variables are typically set in the shell (and shell startup scripts), so that would persist regardless of what you do with Julia. You can check `echo $JULIA_PKG_SERVER` in the shell or `ENV["JULIA_PKG_SERVER"]` in Julia to check if the variable is set.